# update query not working in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

data is coming this form

```
Array
(
[User] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => sxsaxs
        [last_name] => sdsdsd
        [contact_no] => 9569908024
        [address_1] => sdasd
        [address_2] => dsdsdsd
        [country_id] => 1
        [state_id] => 1
        [city_id] => 1
    )

)
```

users_controller.php

```
public function my_account_edit(){

 if(!empty($this->data))
    {
         $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');

     //   echo  $id= $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id'); it's working echo id

        if($this->User->save($this->data['User']))
            {

               $this->Session->setFlash("Account has been saved");
               $this->redirect(array('action' => 'my_account'));

            }


    }
```

but update query not working where id = $this->Auth->user('id');

i am not getting where is problem in my code

Comment: `id` is not getting set as you can see in your print array......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

`$this->data['User']['id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');`

instead of

`$this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');`

Also check this

`$this->User->save($this->data['User'])` make it `$this->User->save($this->data)`

Comment: thanks Rikesh Shah, your answer is right, i have problem due to validation